# How can we get current location as default location in Android google map?

Tags: android, google-maps

In my application i have implemented google map using geocode and autocomplete. I have done in 'Fragment' and the app was a successfully. Now i wanted to display my current location as a default location in my map. Also it should be displayed if i go out from that page and come back.
In my autocomplete text i can search places and it is displayed successfully. All i want is to set my current location as default when i am not searching anything.

i tried adding the following in 'OnResume()'

```
theMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

This helped me to mark my current location, but i am not able to zoom and see my place as by default it displays 'Africa'. even thou my current location is marked.

then i called the following function in 'OnResume'

```
public void getMyLocation()
        {

            theMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.v("current location lat:", ""+location.getLatitude());
                Log.v("current location lng:", ""+location.getLongitude());                 
                theMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));
                CameraUpdate center=
                        CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()),16);
                    CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12);

                    theMap.moveCamera(center);
                    theMap.animateCamera(zoom);
            }
        });
        }
```

After this my current location is displayed continuously after a fraction of seconds. I tried to search a place. But the place is displayed only for 2-3 seconds and again it moved to my current location. I don't know how to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static boolean isMyLocationSet = false;

public void getMyLocation()
        {
            isMyLocationSet = false;
            theMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
                if(isMyLocationSet)
                    return;
                isMyLocationSet = true;
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.v("current location lat:", ""+location.getLatitude());
                Log.v("current location lng:", ""+location.getLongitude());                 
                theMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));
                CameraUpdate center=
                        CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()),16);
                    CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12);

                    theMap.moveCamera(center);
                    theMap.animateCamera(zoom);
            }
        });
        }
```

Try this

P.S. I wrote this in the browser just to give you an idea of what you should do.

if you use `getMyLocation` more than once, please make a non static class member for the location listener and don't make a new one on each call

Comment: What this change it is it makes it get 1 location update before it stops updating it

Comment: it will not make the map follow you everywhere you go

Comment: You can edit your zoom by changing the line `CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12);` make it 15 or so

Comment: you cal also remove `isMyLocationSet = true;` and put it where ever you load venues, this will continue updating locations until you put markers on the map

Comment: is it fixed ? or not ?

Comment: Sorry... a small careless mistake... Your above code works perfect as the way i wanted.. thank you so much :)